# Converting Fortran REAL packing routine to PHP

Tags: php, fortran, pack

I am tasked with converting some Fortran code to PHP and am stumbling at the last hurdle.

In essence the Fortran converts a REAL into a binary CHAR(4) which it ultimately writes to file.

The Fortran (which also confuses me) is as follows:

```
FUNCTION MKS(x)
    CHARACTER (LEN=4) :: MKS             ! The 4-character string which is returned to 
    REAL :: x                            ! The incoming single-precision variable 
    CHARACTER (LEN=1), DIMENSION(4) :: a ! A working variable
    CHARACTER (LEN=4) :: d               ! A working variable
    CALL MKS1(x,a)                       ! Send x - get back a(1), a(2), a(3), a(4) 
                                    ! Note: x will hold the first 32 bits referenced 
                                         ! and a will hold the next 32 bits
d = a(1) // a(2) // a(3) // a(4)     ! concatenate into 1 string (d)
MKS = d                              ! assign string to variable MKS
END FUNCTION MKS

SUBROUTINE MKS1 (b,c)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    CHARACTER (LEN=1), DIMENSION(4)  :: b    ! array with incoming 32 bits
    CHARACTER (LEN=1), DIMENSION(4)  :: c    ! array with each character returned
    INTEGER :: i                             !  DO Loop counter
    DO i=1,4
        c(i) = b(i)
    END DO
END SUBROUTINE MKS1
```

I have attempted to recreate this function using php as follows

```
pack('CCCC', $value & 0x000F, 
           ($value>>8) & 0x000F, 
           ($value>>16) & 0x000F, 
           ($value>>24) &0x000F);
```

But on comparing the output values using the *nix od command shows completely different results.

What is the correct way to pack the equivalent to a Fortran REAL into a char[4] Array in PHP?

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and expected output please.

Comment: Based on the Fortran above I built a very simple test app that uses the REAL input value of 1.450. Outputting this to a file and running od on the the file gives. 

0000000 115040 134631 005077
0000006

Comment: Shouldn't those be `& 0x000000FF` (which can be shortened to `& 0xFF`)? Remember that a hex digit is *half* a byte.

Comment: Trying the 0xFF does not produce the same results as the Fortran. I understand the point, however I'm not entirely clear on the full function (and my interpretation) of the Fortran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be quite simple.

Your FORTAN REAL is stored as an [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) 32 bit floating point number.

The output from your `od` was misleading. Converting it to hex gives the following.

```
0115040 0134631 0005077

0x20, 0x9A, 0x99, 0xB9, 0x3f, 0x0a
```

The first and last bytes of the file are redundant, they are a space and a carriage return respectively. The bit we're after is the middle 4 bytes.

Using `pack` we can convert from floats (**warning** - endianness *is* machine dependant).

The following:

```
var_dump(bin2hex(pack('f', 1.450)));
```

Gives us a familar sequence of bytes.

```
string(8) "9a99b93f"
```

So instead of converting to hex, output that to a file with a space at the start and a carriage return at the end, and you'll have an identical file. (as long as your PHP/machine  configuration doesn't do something mad with floats - but even then if you follow the IEEE 754 spec, you should be able to reproduce it)

Comment: Thanks - much appreciated! :) Interestingly/amusingly the line endings where part of the problem as they were being included in the Fortran as it wrote to file and I was not aware of them.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an extended comment rather than an answer.

You are, in the statement

```
CALL MKS1(x,a)
```

passing a REAL argument where the subroutine expects an array of 4 length-1 characters.  You deserve all the bad things which happen to you :-)  You can only compile this because you haven't required explicit interfaces on your subroutines.

What do you want the 4 characters that your PHP program reads to be ?  If, for instance, your Fortran wrote the `REAL` into 4 bytes in a binary file and your PHP read 4-bytes as 4 single characters would you get the characters you want ?  I'm uncertain of what your requirement is.

Comment: I agree, and indeed the original source code had a few comments to that affect (ignore the compiler warnings, all will be fine) - I didn't write the original :P